# vue command not found on Mac

Tags: vue-cli-3, n

I simply did a `npm install -g @vue/cli` and it didn't work. Trying a `vue --version` after doing the install gave me a bash command not found error.

I tried using sudo as well, but that didn't work. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling and that didn't work. Anyone got ideas for other things to look at?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turned out that the problem was the n node version manager which I had seen also interfere with other things. I wasn't really using it, so I uninstalled it.

`sudo npm uninstall -g n`

n was interfering with npm and npx themselves. They were not updating properly, but now with n gone, I updated them:

`sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

`sudo npm install -g npx@latest`

Then I installed the vue CLI

`npm install -g @vue/cli@latest`

After doing those commands I had the correct versions of npm and npx, and the vue CLI installed correctly as well.

Comment: You just helped me solve a 2-month headache with this answer, thank you so much man. Wish I could double upvote!!

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks 

Comment: Avoid using sudo. You could use something similar to this to set up global packages: https://www.johnpapa.net/node-and-npm-without-sudo/